# How to get this.id on a for each function (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making a function which one gets input checked on page loads, this have an unique id created by shopify, so i got a code in jquery which works fine, but im trying to get it to plain javascript (Vanilla) is anyone able to guide me :)

JQUERY version

```
(function() {
      $("#variantRadios input:checked").each(function() {
        console.log(this.id + " is checked")
      });
})();
```

[image]

Here is Vanilla JS code:

```
(function () {
    const checkVariants = document.querySelectorAll("#variantRadios input:checked");
    checkVariants.forEach((checkVariant) => {
      console.log(this.id + " is checked")
    });
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `() =>`  way (called "arrow function") prevents the value of `this` from changing. So, it does not change to become each element. See [forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [arrow function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [function binding (changing `this`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

However, you don't need to mess with `this` anyway. The `forEach` passes three arguments (you can use zero, one, two, or all three of them), which are: the element, the index, and the entire list.

Again, see [forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Example:

```js
(function () {
    const checkVariants = document.querySelectorAll("#variantRadios input:checked");
    checkVariants.forEach(
      // can also be just `(checkVariant)` as needed
      (checkVariant, index, allCheckVariants) => {
        console.log(checkVariant.id + " is checked")
    });
})();
```

Comment: up vote for explaining the context of "this"

Comment: @Meligy thanks for that comment, is a perfect answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use what is passed to the `foreach`:

```
(function () {
    const checkVariants = document.querySelectorAll("#variantRadios input:checked");
    checkVariants.forEach((checkVariant) => {
      console.log(checkVariant.id + " is checked")
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get element id by **id** property and get if its selected by **checked** property of an element in forEach method

```
(function () {
    const checkVariants = document.querySelectorAll('#variantRadios input:checked');
    checkVariants.forEach((checkVariant) => {
        console.log(`Id = ${checkVariant.id}, is checked = ${checkVariant.checked}`);
    });
})();
```

Comment: The answer gets an attribute, a more accurate way to get the property is `:checked`, which is a valid CSS selector not a non-standard jquery thing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked